# Gulp Clean is triggered when commandline arguments passed into gulp task

Tags: sharepoint, gulp, sharepointframework

I have the following gulp task:

```
build.task('upload', {
    execute: (config) => {
    /* 
       THIS WORKS, BUT ONLY if i do "gulp upload". 
       "gulp upload -u < commandline options >" fails.

    const uname = "johndoe@asdf.com";
    const pwd = "supersecret";
    const siteUrl = "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites";
    const siteCatalogUrl = "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName";
    const catalogName = "AppCatalog";

    console.log(uname);
    console.log(siteUrl);
    console.log(siteCatalogUrl);
    console.log(catalogName);
    */

    const uname = config.args['u'];
    const pwd = config.args['p'];
    const siteUrl = config.args['sU'];
    const siteCatalogUrl = config.args['cU'];
    const catalogName = config.args['c'];

    console.log(uname);
    console.log(siteUrl);
    console.log(siteCatalogUrl);
    console.log(catalogName);


        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const pkgFile = require('./config/package-solution.json');
            const folderLocation = `./sharepoint/${pkgFile.paths.zippedPackage}`;

            return gulp.src(folderLocation)
            .pipe(spsync({
                "username": uname,
                "password": pwd,
                "site": siteCatalogUrl,
                "libraryPath": catalog,
                "publish": true
            }))
            .on('finish', resolve);
        });
    }
});
```

when I'm testing on the command line, i run this like this:

```
 gulp upload
```

the first thing it does call gulp clean ... which blows away the sppkg.  So the upload task fails.

The other artifact that I've noticed, which I can't explain is that when I run the gulp task, i see this:

```
 Build target: SHIP
```

instead of the usual

```
Build target: DEBUG
```

**Output**

```
lab3:search-parts admin$ gulp upload
Build target: SHIP
[14:16:31] Using gulpfile /src/search/gulpfile.js
[14:16:31] Starting 'upload'...
[14:16:31] Starting gulp
[14:16:31] Starting subtask 'clean'...
[14:16:31] Finished subtask 'clean' after 119 ms
[14:16:31] The following tasks did not complete: upload
[14:16:31] Did you forget to signal async completion?
About to exit with code: 0
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

Dunno if it's related, but sharing in case...

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I can consistently recreate the problem, and I found a fix too - albeit - not one that i can use in production.  But I don't know what the root cause of the issue is yet.

To create the problem I simply need to pass in the arguments via the config object.  In other words, I trigger this gulp method via command line like this:

```
  gulp package-solution --ship

  gulp upload --u "johndoe@asdf.com" --p "supersecret" --sU "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName" --cU "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName" --c "AppCatalog"
```

When I run the script, the first thing it does is a gulp clean.
If i comment out all the logic to grab the variables from the config.args[] and just use the hardcoded values... it works.  But I have to make sure that I don't supply the arguments via the commandline.  So in other words, this works:

```
lab3:spparts admin$ gulp upload
Build target: DEBUG
[14:27:27] Using gulpfile /src/sp/spparts/gulpfile.js
[14:27:27] Starting 'upload'...
[14:27:27] Starting gulp
johndoe@asdf.com
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName
AppCatalog
[14:27:27] Uploading spparts.sppkg
[14:27:32] Upload successful 5289ms
[14:27:35] Published file 2408ms
[14:27:35] Finished 'upload' after 7.73 s
[14:27:35] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[14:27:36] Project spparts version:4.3.0
[14:27:36] Build tools version:3.17.11
[14:27:36] Node version:v10.24.1
[14:27:36] Total duration:13 s
```

But this doesn't: (eventhough the js code is still using hardcoded values)

```
lab3:spparts admin$ gulp upload --u "johndoe@asdf.com" --p "supersecret" --sU "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName" --cU "https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName" --c "AppCatalog"
Build target: SHIP
[14:27:27] Using gulpfile /src/sp/spparts/gulpfile.js
[14:27:27] Starting 'upload'...
[14:27:27] Starting gulp
[14:30:36] Starting subtask 'clean'...
[14:30:36] Finished subtask 'clean' after 68 ms
johndoe@asdf.com
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/CatalogSiteName
AppCatalog
[14:30:36] 'upload' errored after 85 ms
 [14:30:36] Error: File not found with singular glob: /src/spparts/sharepoint/solution/spparts.sppkg (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
```

So in summary, I think I can say when I pass in command line arguments, the script calls gulp clean. But I don't know why.

In case it helps, here's my version information:

```
lab3:spparts admin$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

version of sp-build-web is 1.12.1

Comment: Too many snippets without context... hard to tell how you're adding the task in the **gulpfile.js**.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the **upload** task uploads the package to the [tenant|site collection] app catalog? This doesn't solve your problem in the post, but have you considered using the CLI for Microsoft 365? It's got a command that does this for you.

Best of all, there's no code to add to your project's **gulpfile.js** or code to maintain. Works great... using three commands you (1) login, (2) upload, and (3) deploy (ie: trust) the package.

```
# Sign into Microsoft 365
m365 login ${{ m365_target_site_url }} --authType password --userName ${{ m365_user_login }} --password ${{ m365_user_password }}
displayName: 

# Upload SharePoint package to Site Collection App Catalog
m365 spo app add --filePath ${{ sppkg_filepath }} --appCatalogUrl ${{ m365_target_site_url }}/AppCatalog --scope sitecollection --overwrite

# Deploy SharePoint package
m365 spo app deploy --name ${{ spPkgFileName}} --appCatalogUrl ${{ m365_target_site_url }} --scope sitecollection --skipFeatureDeployment
```

Comment: wow.  cool!  I like it.  i'll give it a go.  +1 on your suggestion.

Comment: NP... I used to use this in Azure Pipeline workflows to deploy built packages. Works perfectly.